# Spring Integration : send json as request body and headers in http outbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to invoke an external REST endpoint POST request with a JSON payload which would be getting called from another service through the http inbound gateway.

I am using the below configuration for my application :

```
<int:channel id="xappSearchRequest" />
<int:channel id="xappSearchResponse" />

<int:channel id="xappFilterChannelOutput"/>
<int:channel id="discardFilterChannel"/>
<int:channel id="mutableMessageChannel"/>

<int:filter  input-channel="mutableMessageChannel" output-channel="xappFilterChannelOutput" discard-channel="discardFilterChannel" ref="structureValidationFilter"/>

 <int:transformer input-channel="xappSearchRequest" output-channel="mutableMessageChannel"
    ref="mutableMessageTransformer" />


<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundxappSearchRequestGateway"
    supported-methods="POST"
    request-channel="xappSearchRequest"
    reply-channel="xappSearchResponse"
    mapped-response-headers="Return-Status, Return-Status-Msg, HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS"
    path="${xapp.request.path}"
    reply-timeout="50000"
    request-payload-type="standalone.CFIRequestBody">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator id="xappServiceActivator"
                input-channel="xappFilterChannelOutput"
                output-channel="xappSearchResponse"
                ref="xappSearchService"
                method="handlexappRequest"
                requires-reply="true"
                send-timeout="60000"/>



<int:service-activator id="dicardPayloadServiceActivator"
                input-channel="discardFilterChannel"
                output-channel="xappSearchResponse"
                ref="invalidPayloadService"
                method="getInvalidMessage"
                requires-reply="true"
                send-timeout="60000"/>


<int-http:outbound-gateway id="get.outbound.gateway"
    request-channel="get_send_channel" url="${cms.stub.request.url}"
    http-method="POST" reply-channel="get_receive_channel"
    expected-response-type="standalone.StubResponseBody">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Not able to figure out how to send a JSON payload and custom headers to call the POST endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Custom headers can be mapped to HTTP headers using an appropriate property - `mapped-request-headers`.

There is a full documentation on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping

For JSON request the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` is supplied with the `RestTemplate` which has a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` configured if you have a `jackson-databind` on classpath. Only what you need from your application is to send a POJO which can be serialized into a JSON and what is important - a `MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE` header with an `application/json` value.

Comment: Can you provide me an example where a JSON request is sent as payload in <int-http:outbound-gateway>

Comment: I'm not sure what you need. I believe you have some POJO which really can be as a payload of a message to that to that HTTP gateway. Only what you need is to add a `contenType="application/json"` header before sending to that gateway.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the full configuration and requirement..my integration layer is in between two REST services....

Comment: You don’t show how you send to `get_send_channel`, please

Comment: That is actually where i am stuck...xappServiceActivator has to call the outbound gateway and then return the output to the actual calling service

Comment: You still don’t show who is subscribed to the `xappSearchRequest` channel. It is also not clear if exactly that your service has to call REST or a result of that service has to be transferred over the REST call. Looks like you don’t show the whole picture for your flow...

Answer (score 0):

Figured that out .
I am using a outbound gateway like below :

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="get.outbound.gateway"
    request-channel="postCmsChannel" url="${cms.stub.request.url}"
    http-method="POST" reply-channel="zappSearchResponse"
    expected-response-type="standalone.StubResponseBody">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

The 'postCmsChannel' is the output-channel of service activator :

```
   <int:service-activator id="zappServiceActivator"
input-channel="xappFilterChannelOutput"
output-channel="postCmsChannel"
ref="xappSearchService"
method="handleXappRequest"
send-timeout="60000"/>
```

The 'xappSearchService' is like below :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("postCmsChannel")
MessageChannel postCmsChannel;

 public void handleXappRequest(Message<CFIRequestBody> inMessage){


       /*
       * Map<String, Object> responseHeaderMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       * 
        * //MessageHeaders headers = inMessage.getHeaders(); StubResponseBody
       * info=inMessage.getPayload();
       * 
        * setReturnStatusAndMessage(responseHeaderMap); Message<StubResponseBody>
       * message = new GenericMessage<StubResponseBody>(info, responseHeaderMap);
       * return message;
       */
       inMessage.getHeaders();
       Map<String,String> headerMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
       headerMap.put("X-JWS-SIGNATURE", "dshdgshdgasshgdywtwtqsabh232wgd7wdyt");
       headerMap.put("X-PARTICIPANT-ID", "CMDRV2112BB");
      postCmsChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(inMessage.getPayload())

.copyHeadersIfAbsent(inMessage.getHeaders()).copyHeadersIfAbsent(headerMap).build());

 }

}
```